# Bad Performance of sharpGL inside WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, opengl, sharpgl

I have followed a SharpGL tutorial that can display a rotating block. Initially this only had default colors drawn on it with `gl.Color(r, g, b)`. After this succeeded I tried to texture the cube with an uv map.

When I run the application fullscreen while only coloring the cube (with the sharpGL component covering the entire inside of the application) I get 70~80 fps only for displaying a colored cube. When I enable `OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D` and draw the textures on a singular cube I get 8~9 fps.

Whenever a bitmap is loaded for use as a texture, it is stored in the memory. This drop in framerates only occurs after I enable `OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D` and call `gl.TexCoord(c1, c2)` for all coordinates. Actually moving the object with `gl.Rotate(angle, x, y, z)` does not noticably affect performance.

The provided data for the method including `GetBlockUv` and `CubeCoordinates` are static float-arrays.

Is SharpGL supposed to perform this poorly (i.e. on displaying a singular cube) or is there another reason? Am I doing something wrong that is affecting performance? Is applying textures supposed to affect the performance like that?

The main draw Event happens in a Block:

```
public void DrawBlock(object sender, OpenGLEventArgs args)
    {
        //  Get the OpenGL instance that's been passed to us.
        OpenGL gl = args.OpenGL;

        //  Reset the modelview.
        gl.LoadIdentity();

        //  Move the block to its location
        gl.Translate(Coord.X, Coord.Y, Coord.Z);

        gl.Rotate(angle, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f);
        angle += 3;

        // retrieve the right texture for this block and bind it. 
        Texture blockTex = BlockTexture.GetBlockTexture(gl, _type);
        blockTex.Bind(gl);

        // retrieve the uv map for this block
        float[] uv = BlockTexture.GetBlockUv(_type);

        // retrieve the coordinates for a cube
        float[] cube = CubeCoordinates();


        gl.Enable(OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        //  Draw the cube with the bound texture. 
        gl.Begin(OpenGL.GL_QUADS);
        //
        //
        // Begin by allowing all colors. 
        gl.Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        // since the uv index increments with 2 each time, we will be keeping track of this separately. 
        int uvInd = 0;

        // i denotes the current coordinate. Each coordinate consists of 3 
        // values (x, y, z), thus letting us skip 3. 
        //
        // Seeing as we are creating quads, it is expected that cube.Length 
        // is 3 * 4 * N (where n is a whole number)
        for (int i = 0; i < cube.Length; i += 3)
        {
            // color experiment
            //if (i < cube.Length / 3)
            //{
            //    gl.Color(1.0f, 0.00f, 0.00f);
            //}
            //else if (i < 2 * (cube.Length / 3))
            //{
            //    gl.Color(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    gl.Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            //}

            try
            {
                // set the coordinate for the texture
                gl.TexCoord(uv[uvInd], uv[uvInd + 1]);

                // set the vertex
                gl.Vertex(cube[i], cube[i + 1], cube[i + 2]);
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(
                    "This exception is thrown because the cube map and uv map do not match size");
            }

            // increment the uv index
            uvInd += 2;
        }

        gl.End();
        gl.Disable(OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
```

OpenGL is initialized elsewhere

```
 private void OpenGLControl_OpenGLDraw(object sender, OpenGLEventArgs args)
    {
        //  Get the OpenGL instance that's been passed to us.
        OpenGL gl = args.OpenGL;

        //  Clear the color and depth buffers.
        gl.Clear(OpenGL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | OpenGL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


        // call the draw method of the GameRunner if the 
        // GameRunner has already been created. 
        game?.DrawOpenGL(sender, args);


        //  Flush OpenGL.
        gl.Flush();
    }

    private void OpenGLControl_OpenGLInitialized(object sender, OpenGLEventArgs args)
    {
        //  Enable the OpenGL depth testing functionality.
        args.OpenGL.Enable(OpenGL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    }
```

All the intermediate `GameRunner` does right now is call the `DrawBlock` routine.

What I mainly would want to know is some insight into the performance I can expect of openGL / sharpGL and whether there are better alternatives. I would like to keep using the WPF architecture surrounding the game, but if openGL inside WPF is more meant as a gimmick, that might not be the best course of action.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the exact same issue, and it seems to be the case that either SharpGL or the WPF control itself are using software rendering. I tested this by disabling my main display adapter in Device Manager and got the exact same performance as I did with it enabled.

I don't know how to enable hardware acceleration though, so I don't actually know how to fix the issue.

Comment: According to http://www.dwmkerr.com/sharpgl-2-0-hardware-acceleration/ it should be fixable in SharpGL 2.0 by using a different Render Context Provider. I have not yet tried to actually implement this, but it does explain the performance. Thanks for your time to answer.